# Prevent image from changing size (same height desired)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried so many things but I can't seem to solve this one.

It should be very simple and I am sure there's an easy solution...

The problem is that upon a small screen resolution (on mobile) the table that I have below (which has flags in each of the data cells) squashes so that the image on the far left gets slightly bigger by 2 or 3 pixels because the other two are squashing against it

[image: The Green Arrow Points To A 2 Pixel Difference]

All images are the same size - is there a way to 'force' the height of the images and stop the squashing effect?

Here's my (very basic) HTML (I have NO css)

```html
    <body>
     <table>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">USA</td>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">UK</td>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">Canada</td>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">Germany</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">Australia</td>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">France</td>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">India</td>
        <td><img src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">UAE</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </body>
```

What's a simple approach to this please?

The image height are all the same: 100px

Thanks for all help

Comment: Can you also provide us with the css?

Comment: thanks godof23 - but there is no css

Comment: @henry if you don't have any css ,then where did you  defined hight is 100px

Answer (score 0):

U can manually adjust the image height by giving the `<img>` the attribute height
for example:

```
<td><img height="100" src="flag.png" style="vertical-align:middle;">USA</td>
```

This should do the job :)

Comment: Maybe u can also try it with the `object-fit: cover` css-property and define the height and width of the image as well

Comment: very interesting...I'll try that - I can't right now but I def will

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px) 
/*or whatever size screen you're working with*/
    img {
       height: 10px;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that defining both the height and width may make your pictures become out of proportion.

Another thing to note: you can use pixels or percentages to define the height.

Comment: Since this is happening on a small screen size, you might want to include a media query

Comment: would the media query make the images 100% again? I think it is my WordPress theme screwing with the sizes of the images....

Comment: @henry 1) maybe. It depends on the query. 2) that could conflict, but generally CSS can be overwritten if you use an inline style.

Comment: Although, a media query might overwrite it.